# Micorsoft Azure blob storage secruity

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstore

We  are using MS Azure and developing SAAS based Multi-Tenant Application.

For each Tenant we have BLOB Container Private and assigned to each Tenant.

Also there is a requirement that Client can share files with other client users.

Eg.

1. Client C1 has Container "C1" and it has files "C1f1", "C1f2" and "C1f3".
2. User U1 and U2.  U1 has access permission for C1f1 and U2 has C1f2 access only.

How can we do this in MS Azure Permission or Security? This needs to be done RUNTtime?

Please suggest How can this be done - What is BEST way to do

Comment: One follow up question: Are users specific to a client? In your example above, can it be assumed that users U1 and U2 belong to client C1?

Comment: blob storage is an infrastructure and not built for what you're asking - it will be much more wise to built an application layer that managing access control instead of directly using storage access mechanism

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two options.

Either generate and use SAS tokens  per client/user with the right permissions. With a SAS token you can provide access to a specific resource up to a specific point in time. The disadvantage is that SAS tokens cannot be revoked on a per token basis. You can only revoke *all* tokens by rolling the storage access key that was used to generate the SAS token. Another disadvantage is that you have to provide a SAS token per item you want to grant access to. (For more info see also https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/)

Create a Web Service that encapsulates the Azure storage and serves files to your customers. In this service implement authorization management yourself.